# Properly clear floating elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a bar in which all elements are floating. I have no problem to do this part, but the problem is, when I try to add a new block under this one, I have either a space before my first element in this new block, or a space between my two blocks when I add `clear: both;`.

I already tried with new clearfix hack, but it does not work in my case.

Here is a small codepen I made, to show you the problem I have : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/piDEK. I would like to avoid to have a space between my two blocks, and my h1 should be at left (and not after my ul, you can try by removing the `clear`, in my codepen), obviously.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clear before closeing each parent element which as floated childrens.

Use

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

& CSS

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

I've used this after last `li`, after `ul` & after `.top-bar` div.

**Edit:**

The white line between two divs is due to `#top-bar #left-menu li` element's line height is more than parents height Use,

```
#top-bar #left-menu li {line-height:63px;}
```

Here is modified codepen e.g. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hyJGr)

Answer (score 2):

You could always add `overflow:hidden;` to `#topbar` (and/or `#content`)then remove your separate clearing `div`, so the revised CSS would be:

```
#top-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    /* border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; */
    padding: 0 25px;
    background: green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The purpose of `overflow:hidden` is not to clear floats per se, but to control child content containment by establishing a new [**block formatting context**](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)(BFC) flow root, one feature of BFCs is float containment.

[**More on BFCs from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a
>   Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs
>   and in which floats interact with each other.
>
> A block formatting context contains everything inside of the element
>   creating it that is not also inside a descendant element that creates
>   a new block formatting context.
>
> Block formatting contexts are important for the positioning (see
>   float) and clearing (see clear) of floats. The rules for positioning
>   and clearing of floats apply only to things within the same block
>   formatting context. Floats do not affect the layout of things in other
>   block formatting contexts, and clear only clears past floats in the
>   same block formatting context.

Answer (score 2):

you can clear `float` by giving `overflow:hidden;` on parent element. check the **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KIbLx)**.

Like in your case use in on `section` element.

```
section{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Down voter please explain why -1 . I really hate kind of people who giving negative voting without any proper validation.

Answer (score -2):

Just add a `display:none` to the clearfix DIV's style to remove the unwanted whitespace.

`<div style="clear: both; display:none"></div>`

You will more than likely have more than one of these on your site so I would recommend using a class instead of inline styling.

Comment: "Please consider adding a comment if you think the post can be improved."  Simply down-voting helps no one.  `display:none` resolves the OPs problem of the white space between the two DIVs.

Comment: +1 Not sure what's gone on here, every answer on this question has got downvotes..